# Get User's Date & Time in User' TimeZone

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need the current Date Time from where the user of my website filling a `<form/>`. The Date-Time should be user's Time Zone
I need to get the DateTime without setting the TimeZone

When I use

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

It only returns DateTime in IST.
whether user is from India,USA or UK.

I need the current Date-Time from the User's TimeZone.

I need to insert the value to datetime field in MySql

I didn't ask for user timezone , rather I need the date and time from user's time zone

Comment: I did't ask for user timezone , rather I need the date and time from user's time zone

Answer (score 1):

You've got at least two fast solutions:

1. browsecap or http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api this api returns timezone corresponding to your user IP address
2. you can use javascript and send info about date to your php script:

   new Date().getTimezoneOffset();  - timezone offset :)
   new Date().toString() - returns Sat Jun 11 2016 20:04:35 GMT+0200 (CEST)